# eenvsubst not substituing value for variable

Tags: javascript, json, docker, environment-variables

I have an environment variable which is a form of json representation

```
export ENV={"outer":{"inner":{"key":"apiValue"}}}
```

When I substitute this value using envsubst

```
envsubst < testenv > testapp
```

It replaces with an empty string

testenv

```
JSON.parse($ENV).outer.inner.key
```

testapp

```
JSON.parse().outer.inner.key
```

But if I set it to a simple value like export $ENV=syz this works as expected. Is this achievable?

Here is a complete dockerfile

```
FROM nodesource/jessie:0.12.7

MAINTAINER 


# Create app directory 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# cache package.json and node_modules to speed up builds
ADD src src
ADD package.json package.json
ADD node_modules node_modules

# Install packages for envsubst
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gettext-base

# Substitute dependencies from environment variables
RUN rm src/js/app.js
RUN envsubst < src/js/envapp.js > src/js/app.js
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Have you tried `export ENV='{"outer":{"inner":{"key":"apiValue"}}}'`?

Comment: gives the same result, I think is it because of the JSON.parse statement?

Comment: Why would that have anything to do with it? I assume `envsubst` does a simple string replace. It doesn't know what the text before or after `$ENV` means.

Comment: So , it omits the double quotes, thats why JSON.parse fails on it, any way to  retain the quotes?

Comment: You are mixing things up here. `JSON.parse` is not executed when you run `envsubst < testenv > testapp`. However, if you got it to *not* print an empty string, then yes, it would omit the double quotes because doubles quotes denote string values in a shell. Wrap the whole value in single quotes as I have shown in my first comment.

Comment: Sorry I should have given more background, this is a docker image and at startup I make the replacement and call the JSON.parse on it, so when I ssh into the container I see an empty string for JSON.parse to parse. Would you be interested in looking at the dockerfile? I'll add it

Comment: *"I see an empty string for JSON.parse to parse"* Right. That means the substitution was not successful. That has nothing to do with `JSON.parse` itself though. FWIW, I could replicate the issue, but was able to solve it when I did `ENV=$ENV envsubst`. And again, the value of `ENV` must be inclosed in single quotes.

Comment: thats helpful to know, I am going to try that, were you able to retain he double quotes?

Comment: Yes. Quotes denote strings in bash. So when you do `FOO="bar"` then the value of `FOO` will be `bar` (it's equivalent to `FOO=bar`). If you want to preserve the double quotes, you need to use single quotes around the value. `FOO='"bar"'` assigns the value `"bar"` to `FOO`.

Comment: Thanks it works outside the container, I am guessing that the env variable may not be available when I run the command to replace the string thats why its empty